# Apartar elementos de un arreglo de objetos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un arreglo de objetos que que representan pagos, varios tuvieron as de un intento para ser exitoso, (si un pago con el mismo id tiene varios fallos y un éxito, se considera exitoso, si otro pago tiene puro fallos, se considera fallos.
Debo obtener los id de los pagos fallidos en un nuevo arreglo.

```
const cargos = [
    {
        amount: '50USD',
        invoice_id: 1,
        status: 'failed',
    },
    {
        amount: '50USD',
        invoice_id: 1,
        status: 'success',
    },
    {
        amount: '25USD',
        invoice_id: 2,
        status: 'success',
    },
    {
        amount: '50USD',
        invoice_id: 3,
        status: 'failed',
    },
    {
        amount: '75USD',
        invoice_id: 3,
        status: 'failed',
    }
];
```

Para este ejemplo el resultado debe ser [3]
Intente mediante un ciclo for y también map, pero solo he logrado obtener los casos exitosos, no he logrado ver la manera de separar solo el caso fallido.

```
let exitosos = []
for(let i = 0; i < cargos.length; i++) {
  if(cargos[i].status === 'success') {
    exitosos.push(cargos[i].invoice_id)
  }
}
console.log(exitosos)
```

Ese es el intento de buscar una solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por definición, los casos fracasados son los que NO son exitosos, así que podemos buscar primero los exitosos y luego buscar lo que no están en esa lista:

```js
const cargos = [
    {
        amount: '50USD',
        invoice_id: 1,
        status: 'failed',
    },
    {
        amount: '50USD',
        invoice_id: 1,
        status: 'success',
    },
    {
        amount: '25USD',
        invoice_id: 2,
        status: 'success',
    },
    {
        amount: '50USD',
        invoice_id: 3,
        status: 'failed',
    },
    {
        amount: '75USD',
        invoice_id: 3,
        status: 'failed',
    }
];

const exitosos = cargos
    .filter(cargo => cargo.status === 'success') //buscamos los success
    .map(cargo => cargo.invoice_id); //nos quedamos sólo con la invoice_id

const setFallidos = new Set(); //para evitar repetidos
cargos
    .filter(cargo => !exitosos.includes(cargo.invoice_id)) // buscamos los que no son sucess
    .forEach(cargo => setFallidos.add(cargo.invoice_id)); //los metemos en el conjunto

const fallidos = Array.from(setFallidos); //pasamos a array

console.log(exitosos.toString());
console.log(fallidos.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Según indicas en los comentarios, lo que quieres hacer es esto:

```js
const cargos = [{
    amount: '50USD',
    invoice_id: 1,
    status: 'failed',
  },
  {
    amount: '50USD',
    invoice_id: 1,
    status: 'success',
  },
  {
    amount: '25USD',
    invoice_id: 2,
    status: 'success',
  },
  {
    amount: '50USD',
    invoice_id: 3,
    status: 'failed',
  },
  {
    amount: '75USD',
    invoice_id: 3,
    status: 'failed',
  }
];
let exitosos = []
let fracasados = []
let fracasados_temporal = []
for (let i = 0; i < cargos.length; i++) {
  if (cargos[i].status === 'success') {
    exitosos.push(cargos[i].invoice_id)
  } else {
    fracasados_temporal.push(cargos[i].invoice_id)
  }
}
fracasados_temporal.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!exitosos.includes(item)) {
    if (!fracasados.includes(item)) {
      fracasados.push(item)
    }
  }
})

console.log(fracasados)
```

Y si lo quieres con funciones como filter, map, indexOf esto también funciona:

```js
const cargos = [{
    amount: '50USD',
    invoice_id: 1,
    status: 'failed',
  },
  {
    amount: '50USD',
    invoice_id: 1,
    status: 'success',
  },
  {
    amount: '25USD',
    invoice_id: 2,
    status: 'success',
  },
  {
    amount: '50USD',
    invoice_id: 3,
    status: 'failed',
  },
  {
    amount: '75USD',
    invoice_id: 3,
    status: 'failed',
  }
];

fracasados = []
cargos.filter(el => {
  if (cargos.filter(cargo => cargo.status == 'success').map(cargo => cargo.invoice_id).indexOf(el.invoice_id) == "-1") {
    if (fracasados.indexOf(el.invoice_id) == "-1") {
      fracasados.push(el.invoice_id)
    }
  }
})
console.log(fracasados)
```

Prueba y comenta a ver si te sirve.

Comment: No, el resultado final  debe ser así  [ 3 ], haciendo referencia al id que fallo  dos veces, ósea en el resultado debemos mostrar el id que fracaso el pago, independiente de las veces que se intentó.

Comment: En tu respuesta: fracasados también retorna el id=1, pero ese no es un fracaso ya que se intentó otra vez y allí es succsess, por lo tanto no es un fracaso.

Comment: @AngelVera he actualizado mi respuesta, a ver si ahora ya te sirve.